# Getting User's name from table when they login with e-mail

Tags: php, mysql, database, social-networking

The user table is setup as:
ID | Name | Email | Password

and they login with:

Email | Password

I'm wondering how I can display their 'Name' when they login with their e-mail. What I have so  far that works with email is:

```
session_start();

if (!isset($_SESSION['email'])) {
    header('location: ');
}

include_once('config.php');

$email = $_SESSION['email'];

<!doctype html>
<body> 
    <p><?php echo $email; ?>
```

and that works, but when I try something like

```
$sql = "SELECT name FROM $table WHERE email='$_SESSION["email"]'";
$result = mysql_query($sql);

<!doctype html> 
<body>
    <p><?php echo $result; ?></p>
```

that doesn't work.
Any help is appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`mysql_query()` only returns a *resource*, this needs to be passed to `mysql_fetch_array()` to deal with the returned records; http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php has some examples

Comment: Got an error: "mysql_fetch_array(): supplied argument is not a valid MySQL result resource in line 13"

Comment: I assume you did something like `$resultsArray = mysql_fetch_array($result);`? As you're only expecting to return 1 row, this is good enough (with `SELECT` statements that return multiple rows, you'd want to use a `while` loop).  `$resultsArray` is now an array, and doing `echo $resultsArray['name'];` should print the name.

Comment: should I make a while loop after I run the query? I'm still getting result resource errors

Comment: No - a `while` loop just allows you to go through all returned records.  Without a loop, you just see the 1st record (which in your case will be all you need to do). Can you pinpoint down the problem? Have you tried looking at the SQL statement you're sending to the server to make sure it's what you're expecting, by doing `echo $sql;`?

Comment: Yeah, $sql returns "SELECT name FROM table WHERE email=userone@live.com"
The errors I'm getting are result resource errors from 
$resultsarray = mysql_fetch_array();
$row = mysql_fetch_assoc();

Comment: Try putting single quotes around the email address, so you have `SELECT name FROM table WHERE email='userone@live.com'`

Comment: I put the single quotes but I still get the same error, as of now this is what I have for the script

$email = $_SESSION['email'];

$sql = "SELECT name FROM $table WHERE email='$email'";
$result = mysql_query($sql);
$resultsarray = mysql_fetch_array($result);
$name = $result['name'];

with a result resource error on resultsarray
$sql outputs SELECT name FROM table WHERE email='userone@live.com'

Comment: That's because you've got `$name=$result['name'];` - `$result` is the _resource_, **not** the results array; you need `$name=$resultsarray['name'];` (note also that the column name might be case-sensitive: 'name' vs. 'Name')

Answer (score 1):

tyou did not fetch the result from database 
use the following line

```
mysql_result($result ,0);
```

You can use above function .see the php manual to fetch result from database

Answer (score 1):

You really should include more information, for example what error you're presented with when you attempt the code you included. However,

It would look like you have not correctly escape the string $sql.
Try something like:

```
$sql = "SELECT name FROM $table WHERE email='" . $_SESSION["email"] . "'";
```

Note the dot (.) which concatenates strings instead of evaluating inside a string as you attempted to do.

If you really want to input an array index into the string, you could enclose the variable using {}

```
$sql = "SELECT name FROM $table WHERE email='{$_SESSION["email"]}'";
```

Comment: I'm not sure if this works yet or not since I'm getting errors from mysql_fetch_array() and mysql_result(). I used the first one since I only want the 'name' value. And I don't get any errors previously, it just wouldn't show up.

Answer (score 1):

Do it like this:

```
$sql = "SELECT name FROM $table WHERE email=".$_SESSION['email'];
$result = mysql_query($sql);
$row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);
$name = $row['name'];

<!doctype html> 
<body>
    <p><?php echo $name; ?></p>
```

Regards,

Akke

Comment: Whoops. Should be `$sql = "SELECT name FROM '".mysql_real_escape_string($table)."' WHERE email='".msyql_real_escape_string($_SESSION['email'])."'";`